# Java properties file where property name is suffixed with integer value

Tags: java, jsp, properties

I have come across some Java properties files where properties' names are suffixed with an integer value to denote the order like this:

```
ui.js.include.0 = /file1.js
ui.js.include.1 = /file2.js
```

And then a JSP page will read these properties with a  tag like this:

```
 <c:forEach var="jsInclude" items"${ui.js.include}">
    // some codes to proceed the jsInclude variable
 </c:forEach>
```

Could anyone tell me where this technique comes from? Any official documentation about it?

Answer (score 1):

This technique comes from [Spring framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and its `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Is very common in Spring applications use a `Properties` bean. You can access it from your view this way (assuming you are using `InternalResourceViewResolver`):

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list><value>classpath:config.properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list><value>properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then, in your JSP, you can use `${properties.myProperty}` or `${properties['my.property']}`:

Answer (score 0):

Properties extends Hashtable (which, in turn, implements Map), so is like iterating through a HashMap with Entry.